# is it possible to auto logout user when app is in background for 10 mins in iphone?

Tags: xcode, background-service

I have an app which needs to logout users who are idle for 10 mins, i.e. app is minimized or running in background, is it possible? I searched it a lot but couldn't get solution.Please help me if it is possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Define Logout? Are you keep some connection open in the background ?

Comment: i just want to call a method after 10 mins, without any background support.Is it possible, as a have tried it and the method does'nt call after 5 mins.I have called that method using a timer.

Comment: No this is not possible since when your app is in the background it get suspended thus you can not run any code. The only thing you can do is when the app come back to the foreground is check how long you app has been backgrounded and call the logout code if it has been more then 10 min,

Answer (score 3):

In you appdelegate add property that store the time when you app went into the background.

Like `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *backgroundedDate;`

Then in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` set the date to the current date:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.backgroundedDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

Then when the app comes back to the foreground check the time difference:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {   
    if (self.backgroundedDate) {
        BOOL isTimedout =[self.backgroundedDate timeIntervalSinceNow] <= -(10 * 60);
        if (isTimedout) {
            [yourApiClass logou];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks rckoenes for your help, but my condition is that, i just want to logout the user after exactly 10 min if for that duration the app is in background.As in your suggested code, if the user does'nt open the app for let say 1 day, then the user will be online for 1 day.

Comment: What you want is not possible since you can not execute any code if you app is in the background (suspended).

Comment: The "applicationWillEnterForeground" function works fine, but how can i call from this function to pop first View Controller (In my case the LoginPage). The App crashed every time.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
NSLog(@"Do it once");
self.backgroundedDate = [NSDate date];
});
```

call applicationWillEnterForeground

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
if (self.backgroundedDate) {    
NSLog(@"Forground %@",[NSDate date]);    
BOOL isTimedout = [self.backgroundedDate timeIntervalSinceNow] <= -(5 * 60);
if (isTimedout) {
//Do your work
}
}
}
```